# oracle 12c view different results with MS Access ODBC 12c vs 19c 64bit

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

I have a very strange case: oracle 12c has a view. A MS Access DB connects to this view and stores the view as linked table. In the first test case the connection is done using odbc 19c driver 64bit. In this case the result delivers more records, than the view in oracle itself. In the second test case the connection is done using odbc 12c driver 64bit. In this case the result delivers the same records as the view in oracle itself.

Astonishing, dont you think? What could be the reason for this. We would prefer using odbc 19c driver, is there a way to somehow reconfigure it so that it shows the same results as in oracle? Could be the reason, that the view is quite complex, it uses with clauses, match recognize and so on and that MS Access interprets the the query differently?